# How do I delete an item from my shopping cart?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an ecommerce project and I'm trying to create a function to delete items from my cart, but it's not working. I added a "Delete" button on each item. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const deleteItems = () => {

let buttonDelete = document.querySelectorAll("#deleteItem");
        
    for (const deleteItem of buttonDelete) {
        deleteItem.addEventListener("click", ()=> { 
        const newCart = cart.filter(productos => productos.id != deleteItem.id);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(newCart)); 
          setTimeout(() => {
              location.reload(true); 
          }, 2000); 
        });  
    }
}
deleteItems();
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` with an `id` selector?

Comment: no problem with querySelectorAll, buttonDelete[0] is ready to help you